# RedGate Reflector to recover source code from .net assembly

Tags: c#, reflector, redgate

Quick question.

Can I recover a lost .cs file using RedGate Reflector ?

My assembly is a debug version

Comment: how about trying than asking?

Comment: Indeed.  Probably wants his comments back too.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I assumed that RedGate Reflector would run an installer, and guess what I don't have admin on my machine.  However recovered well, no comments but I have the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open .NET assembly in Reflector, you should be able to switch which language Reflector uses to display the code e.g. `IL`, `VB.NET`, `C#`. There is a dropdown list on the UI menu bar with this selection of languages.

As long as you have all the required external libraries and references, you should be able to copy the C# code form Reflector and try to rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

To make it a little more simple to get the IL code back into a file you should check out [this Reflector Add-in](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx).

More add-ins for Reflector can [be found here](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thank you the first link provided for http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx worked well as a simple addin.