# open an exe in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RedGate Reflector to recover source code from .NET assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134497/redgate-reflector-to-recover-source-code-from-net-assembly)

I have an old program I built in vb.net but have lost all the files except my .exe can i open this in VB.NET (draging it into screen opens aonly some of its information)?

Comment: What do you mean by open, you want to see the source ?

Comment: @Bobby this question is about VB.Net, the other question is about C#. The *question* isn't a duplicate - although the answer is a duplicate, because Reflector can do both. There's no reason why jason should know that, unless he already knows the answer, in which case he wouldn't be asking...

Answer (score 0):

With tools like Reflector, you can try to reverse engeneer it to see its code. If it's indeed in .Ner, you shoule be able to see the code.

HOWEVER, you won't get the exact same code, but a working equivalent. Things like variable names and overall identation might be missing.